# Get EntityManager from Hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have built my application on Hibernate, but now I need to get EntityManager for one third-party module.

Could you please give me some hints how to get JPA objects from Hibernate?

(in my case I have SessionFactory and need EntityManager)

Comment: If it's built only with Hibernate then there are no JPA classes, as SessionFactory is a Hibernate class and from there it's not possible to reach JPA classes. Can you had some more detail to the question?

Comment: You need [Hibernate EntityManager](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/).

Answer (score 14):

I found this in Hibernate 5.2

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 EntityManager em = session.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
```

Comment: `getEntityManagerFactory` is not a method of `org.hibernate. Session `.

Comment: @JingguoYao Have you checked the Hibernate docs https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html Session
extends EntityManager and inherit the getEntityManagerFactory()..

Comment: `@Sunil S` You are right. I am wrong. getEntityManagerFactory is a method of `org.hibernate.Session` for Hibernate 5. I will upvote it later.

Comment: This only works for 5.2 or later. Hibernate 5.0's `Session` doesn't extend  `EntityManager` or `HibernateEntityManager `(https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html).

Comment: Is there any way to do this for hibernate 4? I am stuck there for other reasons.

Comment: This creates separate persistence context. If you want to "share" context between Hibernate Session and JPA EntityManager just cast it:
`Session sesssion = ...; EntityManager = (EntityManager) session`