# Hibernate Search's Initial MassIndexer not working with Wepshphere 8.5, but works fine on TOMCAT

Tags: hibernate, websphere, hibernate-search, websphere-8

We are trying to create the initial elastic search indexes with hibernate search.

Below are the configuration on our system and the exception we are facing.

First the configuration:
**hibernate.cfg.xml:**
    jdbc/dataSource

```
    <property name="dialect">com.csc.pt.hiber.MSSQLDialect2012</property>
    <!-- Session/Transaction -->

    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="transaction.jta.platform" >org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform</property>
    <property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup</property>

    <!-- Use Scrollable Result Set -->
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_scrollable_resultset">true</property>
    <!--  more verbose logs -->
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.startup_check">false</property>

    <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</property>  -->
    <property name="connection.isolation">1</property>

    <!-- performance factors -->
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">8</property>
    <!-- FSIT#179159 Resolution#65256 - Start -->
    <property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
    <!-- FSIT#179159 Resolution#65256 - End -->

    <!--  second level cache -->
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>

<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager">elasticsearch</property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host">http://ip:9400</property>
         <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.index_schema_management_strategy">drop-and-create</property>
         <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status">yellow</property>
         <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.infostream">true</property>
```

**Versions of Hibernate and Hibernate Search we are using:**

[image: Libraries we are using]

Code of the class, used to create the intial Indexes:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public static String createElasticSearchIndex(HibernateSessionFactory hsf) {
        Session session = hsf.current().getSession("");
        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session.getSession());
        try {
            fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now the Exception we are facing.

```
[10/14/18 15:55:56:029 EDT] 00000393 SystemOut     O [org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer](ERROR): HSEARCH000065: Error while rolling back transaction after null
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.rollback(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.rollbackTransaction(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
[10/14/18 15:55:56:029 EDT] 00000393 SystemOut     O [org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler](ERROR): HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000212: An exception occurred while the MassIndexer was transforming identifiers to Lucene Documents
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.begin(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.beginTransaction(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadList(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.loadAllFromQueue(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.run(IdentifierConsumerDocumentProducer.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
[10/14/18 15:55:56:057 EDT] 00000380 SystemOut     O [org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler](ERROR):
 HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000211: An exception occurred while the MassIndexer was fetching the primary identifiers list
org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/websphere/ExtendedJTATransaction]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter.<init>(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter$TransactionAdapter.<init>(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.getTransaction(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform$TransactionManagerAdapter.getStatus(WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.getCurrentStatus(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(StatelessSessionImpl.java:659)
    at org.hibernate.internal.StatelessSessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(StatelessSessionImpl.java:641)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.inTransactionWrapper(IdentifierProducer.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.IdentifierProducer.run(IdentifierProducer.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.runWithErrorHandler(OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.ErrorHandledRunnable.run(ErrorHandledRunnable.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: javax.naming.ConfigurationException: A JNDI operation on a "java:" name cannot be completed because the server runtime is not able to associate the operation's thread with any J2EE application component.  This condition can occur when the JNDI client using the "java:" name is not executed on the thread of a server application request.  Make sure that a J2EE application does not execute JNDI operations on "java:" names within static code blocks or in threads created by that J2EE application.  Such code does not necessarily run on the thread of a server application request and therefore is not supported by JNDI operations on "java:" names. [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/websphere not found in context "java:".]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwExceptionIfDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:522)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.throwConfigurationExceptionWithDefaultJavaNS(javaURLContextImpl.java:552)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:481)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookupExt(javaURLContextRoot.java:485)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextRoot.lookup(javaURLContextRoot.java:396)
    at org.apache.aries.jndi.DelegateContext.lookup(DelegateContext.java:157)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:97)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name comp/websphere not found in context "java:".
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.getParentCtxInternal(NameSpace.java:1970)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.retrieveBinding(NameSpace.java:1377)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookupInternal(NameSpace.java:1220)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.ipbase.NameSpace.lookup(NameSpace.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.urlbase.UrlContextImpl.lookupExt(UrlContextImpl.java:1436)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextImpl.lookupExt(javaURLContextImpl.java:477)
```

> Please let me know, if you require any more information.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Hibernate ORM didn't manage to commit a transaction using the WebSphere transaction manager. This could be a configuration problem in ORM or WebSphere. Are you able to commit transactions in other methods?

Comment: @yrodiere, Thanks for the reply. And yes other modules works as expected. Issue only arises when I try to run the process of creating the initial indexes.
Please suggest, what configurations I could check and share with you for more understanding on your side. It could be from Webshpere or hibernate ORM. Would require a direction to look into for the faulty/wrong/incorrect/required configuration.

Comment: Looking closer at the code, from what I can see in `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform`, explicit transaction management is not supported with Websphere, which I suppose makes sense considering JTA is enabled.  However, the transaction is not started when Hibernate Search creates a session, so Hibernate Search is kind of stuck. You should look for configuration related to transactions, in particular automatic starting of transaction in new sessions. I can't help you much more than that as I'm not familiar with WebSphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long analysis, hard work, even implemented the JPA(RESOURCE_LOCAL). Tried to take the entity manager from my current Hibernate Session and started analysis and search to find the correct way to do this, and found it :).

Got the perfect answer I was looking for through this post on SO's [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43779463/6673843) .

This works like charm. I just had to replace my older code with the code under before-mentioned thread.

**Old code to create the indexes with MassIndexer:**

```
 Session session = hibernateSessionFactory.current().getSession("");
 FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
 fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

**Modified code as below:**

```
Session session = hibernateSessionFactory.current().getSession("");
 EntityManager em = session.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
 FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
 fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

Hope this helps!!