# Facing error TranManagerSet incompatible with TransactionManager On Websphere 8.5. Creating Hibernate Search Index

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-search, websphere-8, jta

I am trying to perform the initial indexing on Elastic server using Hibernate Search, Lucene and using persistence.xml file. The server raises below exception when I run the index creation process on Websphere, this whole process works fine on TOMCAT & TC server. That too only with help of hibernate.cfg.xml. We also have the hibernate.cfg.xml file in the project.

I've also put an earlier question when this was not working with hibernate.cfg.xml and was throwing errors. This is the earlier thread, which later on made me introduce the persistence.xml path. The link is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60951549/hibernate-searchs-initial-massindexer-not-working-with-wepshphere-8-5-but-work).

First the Exception, once the below code lines are executed:

```
   fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
```

**Exception:**

```
00000177 SystemOut     O [org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler](ERROR): HSEARCH000058: 
HSEARCH000116: Unexpected error during MassIndexer operation
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatformException: Could not obtain WebSphere TransactionManager
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(WebSphereJtaPlatform.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.AbstractJtaPlatform.retrieveTransactionManager(AbstractJtaPlatform.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchTransactionalContext.lookupTransactionManager(BatchTransactionalContext.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchTransactionalContext.<init>(BatchTransactionalContext.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.BatchIndexingWorkspace.runWithErrorHandler(BatchIndexingWorkspace.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.ErrorHandledRunnable.run(ErrorHandledRunnable.java:33)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:522)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1153)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:785)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerSet incompatible with javax.transaction.TransactionManager
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereJtaPlatform.locateTransactionManager(WebSphereJtaPlatform.java:63)
    ... 10 more
```

Below are the configuration and code details:

Java Code used:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAManager");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
String message = "";
EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
             tx.begin();

             ProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new ProgressMonitor();
             FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
             fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();

             tx.commit();
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
  <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
                 version="2.0">
       <persistence-unit name="JPAManager" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
     <jta-data-source>jdbc/[youtDataSourceName]</jta-data-source>
<properties>
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />

<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexmanager" value="elasticsearch"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.host" value="http://ip:9400"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.elasticsearch.required_index_status" value="yellow"></property>
         <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.infostream" value="true"></property>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Jar Files related to Hibernate Search, Elastic Search and other dependencies we have currently:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that issue was with the below two jars which I had in my war file on WAS server and were conflicting with the websphere's internal jars.

Removing below two jars solved it:

1. jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final
2. jta.jar

Hope this may help!